# Failed to load ApplicationContext while testing after changes

Tags: spring, unit-testing, maven

I'm having some issues with maven and it's while testing. Yesterday I had working configuration and I was able to execute all of my unit tests. Then I added some classes and stated some changes (but without touching config files) and then after trying to run the tests again, all of them ended with `Failed to load ApplicationContext`. I checked the config files out to the last commit, where they worked for sure, but had the same issue. I fixed it after cloning the whole project and step-by-step adding the changes, no idea what was the difference. Today the same thing happened but after pulling colleague's changes, which were irrelevant to the config files. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show the full stacktrace

Comment: This time there was an error in my colleague's code. Should I assume that when an error is triggered by a code, configured by the applicationContext, the whole context is discarded? Any helpful links on the subject?

Comment: If the changes in the code prevent the spring context from being correctly initialized, then yes. Imagine someone changes the constructor of a class, adds/removes some fields, etc, how would spring be able to instantiate and configure its managed beans?